Consider a Multi Queue level system
I could not able to understand the question mentioned:

Consider a Multi Queue level system consisting of five processes whose arrival time and burst time are given below. Process in Queue Level 1 follows Non-Pre-emptive Priority Scheduling and Queue Level 2 follows SRTF Scheduling. If the CPU scheduling policy is priority based then a higher number represents higher priority. Also we cannot schedule the processes in Queue Level 2 unless Queue Level 1 processes are scheduled. What is the waiting time for Process P4?
Process arrival burst pri queue
P1.     3      4     2     1
P2.     5      9     1     1
P3.     8      4     2     2
P4.     0      7     1     2
P5.     12     6     1     1    



you can follow the below link where i've done the solution for the given problem.just copy the url paste it into the search tab of google the image will be displayed..then you can have a look on the answer.i'm unable to post image directly, sorry for the inconvenience caused hope answer suits you well.
[1]: https://i.sstatic.net/7CUANOeK.jpg
